# MySQL 5.6: Error on loading empty string

Tags: mysql

I am using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and I have tried to handle empty strings (the data is from a csv generated in excel) and converted in comma separated windows file format.

My approach is to replace with NULL using a trigger. The code I am using is below and the data has the following form:

```
PERMNO,date,EXCHCD,SICCD,TICKER,COMNAM
10001,20000131,,,EWST,ENERGY WEST INC
10001,20000229,,4920,EWST,ENERGY WEST INC
10001,20000331,3,,EWST,ENERGY WEST INC
10001,20000428,3,4920,EWST,ENERGY WEST INC
10001,20000531,3,4920,EWST,ENERGY WEST INC
```

I have read and searched for two days. Tried a bunch of things, so I turn to you.

The manual indicates that

> Treatment of empty or incorrect field values differs from that just
>   described if the SQL mode is set to a restrictive value. For example,
>   if sql_mode='TRADITIONAL, conversion of an empty value or a value such
>   as 'x' for a numeric column results in an error, not conversion to 0.
>   (With LOCAL, warnings occur rather than errors, even with a
>   restrictive sql_mode value, because the server has no way to stop
>   transmission of the file in the middle of the operation.)

In my case (using mySQL Workbench as the client) transmission **does stop** and I get the following error message (**not a warning**): Error code 1366 incorrect integer value for column exchange_code. One last note, my code and trigger work like a charm with **any other cell value** but not on the empty string I need it to catch.

Any help you can provide will be extremely appreciated!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dum;

CREATE TABLE dum (
permno INT,
date date,
exchange_code INT(2),
sic INT(4),
ticker CHAR(10),
fname VARCHAR(200));

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON dum
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF NEW.exchange_code = "" THEN SET NEW.exchange_code = NULL;
            END IF;
            IF NEW.sic = "" THEN SET NEW.sic = NULL;
            END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/Desktop/dum.csv'   
REPLACE
INTO TABLE dum
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY '\\'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: Did you forget to include the "...following error message" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Added the error message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your table to:

```
CREATE TABLE dum (
permno INT,
date date,
exchange_code INT(2) DEFAULT NULL,
sic INT(4) DEFAULT NULL,
ticker CHAR(10),
fname VARCHAR(200));
```